# change default app pool identity for new sites

Tags: iis, iis-8.5, application-pools

As we know, by default when you create a new site on IIS8.5, it creates a matching app pool and this is run under the identity **ApplicationPoolIdentity**. We can go into the advanced settings of the app pool and change the identity manually, but is there a way to specify a different user that all new app pools can be run under, by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s a Set Application Pool defaults on the top right Actions Pane. However it will affect existing application pools if they are defaulted as well.

Comment: Should have been more specific, but glad it was found. For everyone else, it’s in the Application Pools view.